# Does she have/has to go to school?

Tags: verb-agreement, third-person, have

Should I use "have" or "has" in this question?

> Does she have to go to school?

or

> Does she has to go to school?

If I should use "have", then what is the rule which makes me not use "has" here?

Comment: Only one verb gets conjugated in a compound verb: here *does* is conjugated, so *have* remains in its bare infinitive form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Does* is the inflected verb here. It has the *s* because it is third person singular present. It is followed by the present infinitive, *have* which is invariant by definition of *infinite* in this context. It does not change with number or gender of the subject or tense of the modal verb.